# How to Add input <type=file multiple /> to mysql database

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating a page that will require four images to be selected and previewed before adding it to a MySQL database. I have the following fields in my database `prodimg1`, `prodimg2`, `prodimg3` and `prodimg4` and I am using `<input type="file" multiple>`. I don't know how to specify which field gets which file like when I am using many `input type=file`

```
$(function() {
    // Multiple images preview in browser
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }

    };

    $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
        imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
    });
});
```

**And the HTML:**

```
<input type="file" multiple id="gallery-photo-add"><div class="gallery">
```